Test Class Failure during deployment with tests due to SOQL on QueueSobject
Got an odd scenario where a test method fails during deployment due to the QueueSobject query not returning the expected queues.
The original query is
SELECT QueueId, Queue.DeveloperName, SobjectType
FROM QueueSobject
WHERE SobjectType = 'Task'

That returns 0 rows during deployment, the queues already exist and are not part of the deployment.

08:30:01.405
(445524653542)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[26]|Aggregations:0|SELECT QueueId,
Queue.DeveloperName FROM QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType = 'Task'
08:30:01.405 (445527169593)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[26]|Rows:0

If we change the query to remove the WHERE clause, we get 288 queues and the test passes.
Really quite confused by this as, other classes use similar query and work as expected:

08:29:55.85
(439258266492)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[787]|Aggregations:0|SELECT QueueId,
Queue.Name FROM QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType = 'Case'
08:29:55.85 (439268763521)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[787]|Rows:158

What's more confusing is that if we run the test class as the deployment user post deployment, it returns the expected queues.

I have not being able to replicate this outside of the Github Action unfortunately, but do not understand how that would impact it.

Did you check if the apex version are uptodate and you compiled all classes in prod?

Yes it is version 60.0, and it is only in sandbox atm, goes to prod June.
